# SanDisk Cruzer Blade on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, 16.04, usb-drive

I have a 128G USB stick but Ubuntu doesn't mount it, doesn't see its partitions and doesn't let me format it.

dmesg:

```
[ 3124.001070] scsi host8: usb-storage 3-6:1.0
[ 3125.001042] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3125.001511] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3125.002864] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[ 3125.004512] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3125.004516] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3125.004788] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3155.886694] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3186.917281] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3217.963891] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3248.930474] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3259.170022] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.409403] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.649387] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3285.888788] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3286.017438] sd 8:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 3286.017447] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3286.017450] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3286.017452] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 3286.017455] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3286.017491] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017499] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017502] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 3286.017505] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017509] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017512] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017516] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017518] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 3286.017521] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017525] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017533] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017537] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017540] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3286.017542]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 3286.017654] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3507.045052] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 3532.849931] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 3534.530519] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[ 3534.530525] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3534.530528] usb 3-6: Product: Cruzer Blade
[ 3534.530530] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 3534.530532] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 4C530000360119115540
[ 3534.531122] usb-storage 3-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3534.532419] scsi host9: usb-storage 3-6:1.0
[ 3535.530816] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3535.531338] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3535.532651] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[ 3535.534275] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3535.534282] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3535.534600] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

dmesg on a USB2 port:

```
[13712.795990] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13714.424628] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[13714.424632] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13714.424634] usb 3-6: Product: Cruzer Blade
[13714.424636] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[13714.424637] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 4C530000360119115540
[13714.425386] usb-storage 3-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[13714.425523] scsi host10: usb-storage 3-6:1.0
[13715.425303] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[13715.425690] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[13715.427008] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[13715.428665] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[13715.428668] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[13715.428953] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[13746.221203] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13777.190106] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13808.175044] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13839.208027] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13849.452206] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13865.692838] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13865.988708] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13876.229026] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[13876.357892] sd 10:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[13876.357912] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[13876.357919] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[13876.357924] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[13876.357931] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[13876.358015] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358042] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358049] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[13876.358059] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358069] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358080] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358090] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358097] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[13876.358105] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358116] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358136] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358147] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358158] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[13876.358163]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[13876.358568] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

fsck:

```
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sd
/dev/sda   /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb 
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext2: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sdb
Possibly non-existent or swap device?
```

lsusb:

```
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bdb:193e Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Trying to format anyway:

```
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sdb -I
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdb: No such device or address
```

Couldn't find any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
In the Disks app I found this:

[image]

Another thing I tried:

```
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb 
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
tune2fs: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Another thing I tried is changing the state of the device and formating it:

```
sela@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo -s
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~# cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/7\:0\:0\:0/state 
offline
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~# echo running > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/7\:0\:0\:0/state 
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~# cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/7\:0\:0\:0/state 
running
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~# mkdosfs -v -n 'SELA111' -I /dev/sdb 
sdb
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~# mkdosfs -v -n 'SELA111' -I /dev/sdb  
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdb: No medium found
root@sela-ThinkPad-T440p:~#
```

Is this stack trace related?

```
[ 6478.677549] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 6480.129365] INFO: task kworker/u16:4:4979 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 6480.129369]       Not tainted 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu
[ 6480.129370] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 6480.129372] kworker/u16:4   D ffff8804033a3848     0  4979      2 0x00000000
[ 6480.129380] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[ 6480.129381]  ffff8804033a3848 ffff8804261f6a80 ffff88042c2d5280 ffff880425003700
[ 6480.129383]  ffff8804033a4000 ffff88043e396d00 7fffffffffffffff ffffffff81822310
[ 6480.129385]  ffff8804033a39a8 ffff8804033a3860 ffffffff81821b15 0000000000000000
[ 6480.129387] Call Trace:
[ 6480.129392]  [<ffffffff81822310>] ? bit_wait+0x60/0x60
[ 6480.129395]  [<ffffffff81821b15>] schedule+0x35/0x80
[ 6480.129397]  [<ffffffff81824c35>] schedule_timeout+0x1b5/0x270
[ 6480.129401]  [<ffffffff813bb526>] ? submit_bio+0x76/0x170
[ 6480.129403]  [<ffffffff81822310>] ? bit_wait+0x60/0x60
[ 6480.129405]  [<ffffffff81821044>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa4/0x110
[ 6480.129407]  [<ffffffff8182232b>] bit_wait_io+0x1b/0x70
[ 6480.129409]  [<ffffffff81821ebd>] __wait_on_bit+0x5d/0x90
[ 6480.129413]  [<ffffffff812481d0>] ? blkdev_readpages+0x20/0x20
[ 6480.129416]  [<ffffffff8118cd0b>] wait_on_page_bit+0xcb/0xf0
[ 6480.129421]  [<ffffffff810c3bc0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x40/0x40
[ 6480.129423]  [<ffffffff8118cf39>] wait_on_page_read+0x49/0x50
[ 6480.129426]  [<ffffffff8118e56d>] do_read_cache_page+0x8d/0x1b0
[ 6480.129428]  [<ffffffff8118e6a9>] read_cache_page+0x19/0x20
[ 6480.129430]  [<ffffffff813ce77d>] read_dev_sector+0x2d/0x90
[ 6480.129433]  [<ffffffff813d51fd>] read_lba+0x14d/0x210
[ 6480.129435]  [<ffffffff813d5ab2>] efi_partition+0xf2/0x7d0
[ 6480.129438]  [<ffffffff813f4ffb>] ? string.isra.4+0x3b/0xd0
[ 6480.129440]  [<ffffffff813f6f39>] ? snprintf+0x49/0x60
[ 6480.129442]  [<ffffffff813d59c0>] ? compare_gpts+0x280/0x280
[ 6480.129443]  [<ffffffff813cfb2e>] check_partition+0x13e/0x220
[ 6480.129445]  [<ffffffff813cf060>] rescan_partitions+0xc0/0x2b0
[ 6480.129447]  [<ffffffff812490cd>] __blkdev_get+0x30d/0x460
[ 6480.129449]  [<ffffffff8124968d>] blkdev_get+0x12d/0x340
[ 6480.129453]  [<ffffffff812274f9>] ? unlock_new_inode+0x49/0x80
[ 6480.129455]  [<ffffffff81248068>] ? bdget+0x118/0x130
[ 6480.129459]  [<ffffffff813ccb13>] add_disk+0x403/0x490
[ 6480.129463]  [<ffffffff815592a1>] ? update_autosuspend+0x51/0x60
[ 6480.129465]  [<ffffffff8155936c>] ? __pm_runtime_use_autosuspend+0x5c/0x80
[ 6480.129469]  [<ffffffff815c0845>] sd_probe_async+0x115/0x1d0
[ 6480.129471]  [<ffffffff810a30a8>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
[ 6480.129474]  [<ffffffff8109a175>] process_one_work+0x165/0x480
[ 6480.129476]  [<ffffffff8109a4db>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
[ 6480.129477]  [<ffffffff8109a490>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[ 6480.129479]  [<ffffffff8109a490>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[ 6480.129481]  [<ffffffff810a06a8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[ 6480.129483]  [<ffffffff810a05d0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[ 6480.129484]  [<ffffffff81825f8f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[ 6480.129486]  [<ffffffff810a05d0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[ 6488.917955] usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: @Sneetsher It says "new high-speed..." wherever I connect it. In the ports with the ss and in those without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reasons, this device is removed suddenly by kernel or USB controller in non clean way, So it leaves those `/dev` nodes artifact.

#### It's a USB2 device!

As I see the spec data of [SanDisk Cruzer Blade](https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/cruzer-blade).:

```
Capacity    128 GB   64 GB    32 GB    16 GB    8 GB     4 GB
Generation  USB 2.0  USB 2.0  USB 2.0  USB 2.0  USB 2.0  USB 2.0
```

It should be a USB2 device. So it could be buggy with USB3 port

```
usb 3-6: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
...
usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
```

Change it to another USB2 port your laptop should have 2 ports already ([Lenovo ThinkPad T440p spec.](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t440p/#tab-tech_specs)) .

It is clear that `xhci_hcd` detected it as a USB2 device from its description

> usb 3-6: new *high-speed* USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd

USB3 devices should get `super-speed` or `super-speed+`. Reference: [Wikipedia: USB, Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Version_history)

#### Option 1. Disable USB3 from the BIOS

It's [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t440p_ug_en.pdf) mentions:

- 2 left side, as USB3
- 2 right side, as USB (? If it have `+` sign it is a USB2)
- The BIOS have option to disable USB3 on the 2 shared ports between USB2 & USB3. Which side? I don't know!

  So may be the shared ports are those on the right side. Disable the USB3 from the BIOS an see what are the new outputs of `dmesg` on both sides, plus output of `lsusb`.

#### Option 2. Upgrade BIOS/UEFI

There is a new release:

> BIOS Update Utility Size:5.7 MB 2.37 4/28/2016

The release note mentions counted USB issues, most interesting is this one:

> ```
> <2.19>  UEFI: 2.19 / ECP: 1.08
> - (Fix) Fixed an issue that might fail to boot the computer remotely.
> - (Fix) Fixed an issue where USB 3.0 device detection might fail when the device
>         was attached via the USB 3.0 Hub and the USB 3.0 Mode option was set to
>         Enabled in ThinkPad Setup.
> ```

Comment: Are the ports without the ss USB2 ports? If so, it doesn't help connecting the stick there. It behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I added it. This is after waiting about 30 seconds. I'll keep it plugged in and see if anything new pops up in a few minutes.

Comment: Now that I look at it. I think the first one was also on the same port.

Comment: @selalerer yes it is and it is a USB3, still!!!

Comment: but this is one of the ports on the right side of the laptop that doesn't have the ss marking.

Comment: @selalerer Could I ask for which option did work for you?